# Where is metadata for custom list view on Task?

Tags: metadata, tasks, list-view

I have created a custom list view on Task.  In Workbench it is displayed under Task within metadata type 'ListView'.

When I pull my metadata using API v43 I can't find the xml definition for it anywhere.

It is not listed as an Unsupported Metadata Type in the Metadata API Developer Guide for Summer '18.

How can I retrieve the metadata for it so that I can then deploy it?

Comment: Got the same issue, Unable to retrieve/deploy list view on task

Answer (score 4):

Adding onto @sfdcfox and @DavidReed answers, you could do a direct pull of the list view with:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ListView:Task.My_Task_List_View -u MyConnectedOrg
```

Answer (score 3):

They should appear in the Activity object (src/objects/Activity.object). Note that "private" list views will not appear in the Metadata API.

---

Example SFDX command:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject:Activity
```

Comment: Thank you @David-Reed and sfdcfox, that is what I expected, but a custom list view, that is not private, on Task, does not show up in Task.object.

Comment: @MikeA did you ever resolve this issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Andreas86 I didn't find it anywhere.  We had to make it a manual deployment step.

Comment: @MikeA I missed this comment. It actually appears in a CustomObject called Activity. That was my mistake.

Comment: @Andreas86 I edited my answer after realizing my mistake. You can use the Activity CustomObject to get at these list views.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, I had that thought before I commented yesterday and gave it a quick test.  I created a custom list view on Task, shared with all, pulled metadata with MavensMate but still couldn't see the list view in Activity.object.  Have you seen the list view metadata with your own eyes?

Comment: @MikeA It might be a MM problem or something. Try using sfdx or another tool and see if you can retrieve the values. I have definitely gotten the list views using sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve and force:source:retrieve.

Comment: @sfdcfox - maybe this is why - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000272282&language=en_US&type=1 - "In Summer 18 release, Lightning Task List View do not show up in metadata for outbound change set and/or other deployment tools"

Comment: @MikeA Oh. So, the moral of the story is, create your list views in Classic? That's kind of an oddly specific limitation of LEX.

Comment: @sfdcfox if you create the list view in Classic it shows up in Activity.object - yay! - but when you open the Task tab in LEX the list view is not there - boo!

Comment: @Andreas86 - see updates to this thread

Comment: @sfdcfox Can we retrieve listview of object like PermissionSetGroup ?

Answer (score 1):

List views are part of the `CustomObject` metadata entity. If you open up a `.object` file (the XML source for a custom object), you'll see top-level entries like this:

```
<listViews>
    <fullName>All</fullName>
    <filterScope>Everything</filterScope>
    <label>All</label>
</listViews>
```

that define each of your list views.

Note that the `CustomObject` type in your `package.xml` is also used to pull customizations like list views for standard objects. If you include a standard object in your `package.xml`,

```
<types>
    <members>Task</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

You'll get back all of its non-private list views.

If you just pull down custom *fields* on a standard object (with the `CustomField` type), you won't get the list views back.

You can select list views individually with the `ListView` type in your `package.xml`:

```
<types>
    <members>Account.My_List_View</members>
    <name>ListView</name>
</types>
```

but they'll still be stored in your `.object` files.